# Is SQL Server support index condition pushdown?

Tags: sql-server

MySQL supports index condition pushdown optimization. Does SQL Server support it? I didn't find any information on Google.

[MySQL Server - Index Condition Pushdown Optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-condition-pushdown-optimization.html)

> Index Condition Pushdown (ICP) is an optimization for the case where
> MySQL retrieves rows from a table using an index. Without ICP, the
> storage engine traverses the index to locate rows in the base table
> and returns them to the MySQL server which evaluates the WHERE
> condition for the rows. With ICP enabled, and if parts of the WHERE
> condition can be evaluated by using only columns from the index, the
> MySQL server pushes this part of the WHERE condition down to the
> storage engine. The storage engine then evaluates the pushed index
> condition by using the index entry and only if this is satisfied is
> the row read from the table. ICP can reduce the number of times the
> storage engine must access the base table and the number of times the
> MySQL server must access the storage engine.

Comment: Worry less about specific efficiency features, worry more about writing efficient code and designing efficient tables using the features each database engine supports.

Comment: Yes it does, see https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/predicate-pushdown-and-why-should-i-care/ba-p/385946

Comment: In particular, in SQL Server everything's an index, and the question doesn't even make sense.  Yes, of course SQL Server applies criteria while reading an index, and doesn't have to fetch the full row before applying a WHERE clause.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft The question is perfectly coherent, given an understanding of what "index condition pushdown" is in MySQL. It's just off-track because the architectures aren't identical and the terminology is not shared. But clearly an RDBMS can satisfy a query by having a storage subsystem retrieve all data associated with a table, and then having a logical subsystem above the storage subsystem which evaluates all of the data returned by the storage subsystem in order to apply predicates, with no filtering done by the storage subsystem.

Comment: So is this something like the `INROW` predicate push down mentioned here? https://www.sql.kiwi/2011/07/bitmap-magic.html

Comment: I think this discussion would be clearer if people read what [index condition pushdown actually means in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/index-condition-pushdown-optimization.html)

Comment: My point was that the basic behavior that ICP avoids never happens in SQL Server.  IE "Without ICP, the storage engine traverses the index to locate rows in the base table and returns them to the MySQL server which evaluates the WHERE condition for the rows".  SQL Server applies predicates as it reads an index, if possible, but the interface between the "storage engine" and the "query engine" are different in the two platforms.  SQL Server's storage engine delivers pages and column segments to the buffer cache, where they are read by query plan operators.

Comment: Sure, that's what I meant by "the architectures aren't identical and the terminology is not shared". So we can't perform a one-to-one mapping in terms of features. But what we can say is that at the very least SQL can use indexes to minimize page reads, and can apparently go even further than that (per Martin's link, although I know none of the details of that feature). Hence the "essence" of the logical idea is in SQL even though the implementations don't have a direct equivalence.

Comment: Moreover, *even if* you prefer the answer is "there is no direct equivalent of that feature in SQL Server due to architectural differences", that is still a coherent answer to a coherent question.

Answer (score 2):

Just to tie a bow on this one...

MySQL and SQL Server use different architectures, so a direct map between the implementation details of the two engines can't be done at a feature by feature level.

For example, we have a problem here with equivocation on the term "storage engine", because the two systems draw different boundaries around what the responsibilities of the "storage engine" are.

So in order for an answer to make sense to you, you need to have some understanding of the internal architecture of SQL Server. I think [this video by Kevin Kline](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=34VqSliEfsc) is the best "quick" overview of that you're likely to find, despite the fact that it's now 7 years old, even if some details might have changed a bit since then. If you want more details on how the query processor thinks, [this video by Brent Ozar](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ShAtKVTsq7Y) is also good. You might also want to read [this article by Paul Randal](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/inside-the-storage-engine-anatomy-of-a-page/) about the structure of a page, and the linked article on the structure of a record in a page.

In that first video, we see that the "storage engine" in SQL server concerns itself with "pages", which are 8KB chunks of data. In the context of your question, we're mostly concerned with data and index pages. The storage engine concerns itself with pages, not rows (although caveat here, see Martin's link in the comments on your question. I don't fully understand the feature being referenced there).

So, when you run your query, something has to figure out which "pages" are needed to satisfy the request. This happens in a couple of phases. The "optimizer" figures out a logical "query plan", and sends that plan to the storage engine, which figures out how to get the pages that are needed from the objects indicated by the query plan.

SQL doesn't have to pull every page associated with the logical object out of the storage engine and send it to the query processor in order to get your data. Indexes are used to be able to say things like "I know the rows you need are on exactly this page", or "I know the rows you need are between this page and that page". So the IO operations are definitely "pruned" by the optimizer, which is an optimization that partly maps to the "ICP" function in MySQL.

Then, once the pages required have been selected and are made available to the query processor, the query processor (which always deals with pages in RAM, not on disk!) then deals with the rows on those pages. As Daivd Browne mentioned, it doesn't have to "read a whole row" in order to evaluate your where clause.

So the "ICP" feature of MySQL maps to multiple subsystems in SQL, not just "the storage engine". But when you add it all up, the result is "essentially" the same.